# Getting a RESTful webservice with Spring to understand a JSON-string

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I'm very new to using Spring, and all the things involved, but I'm trying to get through this.

I'm trying to make a service, using the Spring MVN and Gradle, to understand a JSON-formatted String. It's all made in Java.
But I can't get it to work as it should, at all.

This

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/toggle")
public @ResponseBody String sendCommand(@RequestParam(value="IP") String IP){
//body
}
```

Is a method in my Controller, but, when I send the following JSON-formatted String

```
{"IP":"192.168.1.9"}
```

I still get the Response Code 400.

I've tried different variations, one example using a @RequestBody instead, with an own class for the indata. And another where I recieve a HttpEntity, to watch whether the String was recieved correctly. While the String is recieved correctly, I can't get my code to "read" it.

I can go to localhost:8080/toggle, and through HTTP set the variables, say:

```
http://localhost:8080/toggle?IP=192.168.1.9
```

works.

Where would you suggest to continue troubleshooting?
Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT:
Wow. Thanks a lot for quick replies, I was expecting a day or two to go without replies, instead I got your help within minutes. I knew this site was good, but you are great, thanks!

That said, I made a new class called Ident, which has only a private String variable, with constructor, setter and getter.
Now I have

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/toggle")
public @ResponseBody String sendCommand(@RequestBody Ident ident) {
//body
}
```

I still get 400 sending the same String though.

And while it would work using a @PathVariable, I'd like getting this to work, because now I'm only experimenting with it. It will be used to send more than only the IP later on.

I'm using 
    @ComponentScan
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
in the main-file, might that have something to do with things - that it gets set up wrong?

Comment: You should definitely be using @RequestBody.  Does that JSON object represent a Java object that you expect to be deserialized by Jackson or are you planning to parse it by hand?

Comment: Are you getting a stack trace on the server?  Have you checked the logs?

Comment: EDIT: Eh, the formatting broke, I'm adding this into the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing to different thing (request parameters and json objects).

In order to catch the POSTed `{"IP":"192.168.1.9"}` you need to do something like the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/toggle")
public @ResponseBody String sendCommand(@RequestBody String json){
   final YourObject yourObject = mapJsonToObject(json);
   final String ip = yourObject.getIp();
//body
}
```

You also need to create a class that corresponds to the json and map that json to the class (using a library like jackson).

If you want to forgo the creation of the intermediate object (which I do not propose you do since it makes the code cleaner), you could just extract the IP from the json String using standard JDK methods

Comment: Using a library like Jackson is not "needed", though I agree it is much cleaner.

Comment: You are absolutely right that it is not technically needed, in such a simple case the developer could easily create the object on his own

Answer (score 0):

Your Method Should be like,

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/toggle/{IP}")
 public @ResponseBody String sendCommand(@PathVariable String IP){
   //body
 }
```

here IP is placeholder that can accommodate any passed IP.

and your URL request should be like

**http**://localhost:8080/toggle/192.168.1.9  // [as per RESTful URL principle ]

Comment: This will work, but it assumes he cares about making his services RESTful.

Comment: This is not correct. You need to swap `@RequestParam` with `@PathParam`

Comment: In Spring MVC it's `@PathVariable`, not `@PathParam`.

Comment: Another thing to note, if your code is not compiled with debug information you'll have to specify the path name in the annotation: `@PathVariable("IP")`